# Promise starts too early

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following promise:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  setTimeout(()=> { resolve('Hello')},4000);
});
```

And later, I call it like this:

```
promise.then((msg) => {console.log(msg)});
```

I was expecting that the 'Hello' message is displayed 4 seconds after the call to `then` due to the timeout, but it is actually displayed right away...

It is sure something I'm missing: what?

Comment: It is working as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And I call it like this

You don't "call" a promise. It's not a function (though it does have methods). From the question I understand that you did the first part (`const promise = new Promise(/*...*/);`), and then **later** did the second part (`promise.then(/*...*/);`), and you expected the timer to start when you did `then`, not when you did `new Promise`.

But the way Promises work, your timer was started when you did `new Promise`, not later when you called `then`. The function you pass into `new Promise` (the *promise executor* function) is called **synchronously** and **immediately**. Its purpose is to start the operation that the promise is going to report the completion of.

This may help make it a bit more clear:

```js
const start = Date.now();
function log(msg) {
    const elapsed = String(Date.now() - start).padStart(4, " ");
    console.log(`${elapsed}: ${msg}`);
}

log("A");
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    log("B: Starting 5000ms timer");
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("Hello");
    }, 5000);
    log("C");
});
log("D: Waiting 2000ms before calling `then`");
setTimeout(() => {
    log("F: Calling `then`");
    promise.then((msg) => {
        log("G");
        log(msg)
    });
}, 2000);
log("E");
```

Notice that the output is

```
   0: A
   1: B: Starting 5000ms timer
   2: C
   2: D: Waiting 2000ms before calling `then`
   2: E
```

and then about two seconds later:

```
2002: F: Calling `then`
```

and then about three seconds later (five seconds since the start)

```
5002: G
5004: Hello
```

Things to note:

- The promise executor was run synchronously and immediately, and start its 5 second timer
- It doesn't matter when you call `then`. I waited to call `then` for 2 seconds, but still got the fulfillment callback after a **total** of 5 (not 7) seconds

---

What I describe above is the standard behavior for promises. There are (unfortunately, in my view) a small number of promise-like things out there that behave slightly differently, that *do* wait for the first call to `then` before they start their process. Those are **not typical**, but sadly they do exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. It is much clearer now!

Comment: @Christian68 - You're welcome! Since it seems I understood the question correctly, I've taken the liberty of editing the question to make the time element clearer. If I've got the edit wrong, please use the "rollback" feature in the edits list to reverse it. Happy coding!

Comment: No worries, your understanding was correct!